# Generating a new game window

Tags: java

> [MAIN Game.java](https://pastebin.com/JRkrtd9k)
>
> [MouseInput.java](https://pastebin.com/MXmXWAPS)
>
> [Menu.java](https://pastebin.com/5xmd7h2Z)
>
> [HighScoreMenu.java](https://pastebin.com/Y4ub5mqz)
>
> [Enemy.java](https://pastebin.com/ipzeNw4b)
>
> [BufferedImageLoader.java](https://pastebin.com/0f367vLv)

I had this code working at one point but I am having trouble knowing what the issue is. I am trying to start with a `joptionpane`
and then the gui click game which gets created by below.Then back to `joptionpane`. THEN the click game, this is where it messes up at the RECREATION. It errors or passes the click game. Check the pastebins.

```
Game game = new Game();
game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * 
SCALE));
game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * 
SCALE));
game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * 
SCALE));

JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);
frame.add(game);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
game.start();
```

I've tried resetting my code to the default, tried creating the game i want again with `joptionpane` included but it no longer works.It seems like my computer does not wanna play it anymore? I have made changes but I just don't know what turned off my function.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    init();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (running) {
        // this would be the game loop
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            final int i = updates++;
            delta--;
        }

        render();
        frames++;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            //System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, FPS " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}


private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2000);
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }
```

---

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:4006)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3980)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4503)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3857)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3781)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)
    at com.game.src.main.Game.render(Game.java:662)  - this is createbufferstrategy 
    at com.game.src.main.Game.run(Game.java:618)     - this is render();
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)         - this is createbufferstrategy
```

Wondering what I kicked off. Thanks for any help.

Comment: “It errors or passes the click game.” It seems like error messages might be important.  Edit your question and show us what those error messages are.  If it’s a stack trace, make sure to include the entire stack trace, including all “Caused by:” sections.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the post the errors are there.

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true)` is not guaranteed to make the JFrame visible immediately.  It may ask the system to show the window, and the system may provide the new state at a later time.  Try `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> game.start());`.  You could also add a WindowListener before the frame is shown, and run game.start() from the windowOpened method.

Comment: Please include all code in the question, not on external websites you link to. But before doing so, please reduce the code in your question to a [MCVE]. Very often by creating a [MCVE] you already find the bug yourself. The purpose of Stack Overflow is not for us to debug your code, the purpose is for you to ask a meaningful and useful (to future readers) question about a general coding problem that you encountered when debugging yourself. If the question is specific to your application, it's not useful to other people and needs to be rewritten or not posted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Game.State = STATE.MENU;
```

This was needed in front of the creation of the game state.
This what was there.

```
Game.State (STATE.MENU);
```